# Can't show select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, simple-form

I have 3 models:

Lending
Equipment
Category

Lending belongs_to equipment

Equipment belongs_to :category
Equipment has_many   :lendings

Category has_many :equipments

I want to show a selectbox in lending's form with the categories.But there's not any association between Lending and Category models.I can't see an association between these two models(Lending and Category) but with Equipment and Category yes.
How do I do that? Ah I'm using simple form!
Excuse my english!

Answer (score 0):

you have generated a textbook example of `has_many :through`:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

A has_many :through association is often used to set up a many-to-many connection with another model. This association indicates that the declaring model can be matched with zero or more instances of another model by proceeding through a third model. For example, consider a medical practice where patients make appointments to see physicians. The relevant association declarations could look like this:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using delegation in this case. Add this line to your `lending.rb` file.

`delegate :category, to: :equipment`
This will return the concerned category.